# Parsing string containing possibly two json objects

Tags: python, json, serialization

How do I differentiate and parse data from strings like this to json objects:

```
"[{"months": 12, "product": "car"}, {"months": "12", "product": "bike"}]"

"[{"months": 12, "product": "car"}]"
```

I need to know the count of json objects in string and get values based on that

Comment: It's not a duplicate since it contains multiple JSON objects!

Comment: Those are two strings. And if your problem is that you don't know how to split a string. Then ask the question differently.

Comment: @thevangelist, well, did you try passing your JSON string to `json.loads()` and see what the result is?

Comment: Load it and then do whatever you'd normally do that distinguishes between a list with 1 element or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
json_string = '[{"product": "car", "months": 12}, {"product": "bike", "months": "12"}]'

import json
data = json.loads(json_string)
print data[0], len(data)
```

Comment: How do i get the second part?